# Ubuntu.Components for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, application-development

I read somewhere that to develop apps using Ubuntu.Components, 14.10 is needed. Is there no workaround to make it work on 14.04?

Or is there any older version of Ubuntu.Components for 14.04? If so, where can I find it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I am using QTCreator.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need Ubuntu SDK (Software Development Kit) for your Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, don't you? There are two decision in this case (not enough information from you - do you plan to use QTCreator or QML?):

1. Search **"Ubuntu SDK"** in **"Ubuntu Software Center"** (may be you did already and it was not suitable for you needs)
2. Or, if previous decision is not acceptible, run in terminal:

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk

More information you can find here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am planning to use QTCreator. In fact, I have already installed it and Ubuntu SDK as you said from the terminal. But I get the error "Ubuntu.Components 1.1 Not Found". So I wanted to know if there was any kind of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The development environment and target environment are different. In your case, you want to develop apps for Ubuntu Touch (currently based on 14.10, target environment) on your 14.04 machine (development environment). You can do so in 2 ways,

1. Create an Ubuntu Emulator using Ubuntu SDK. This will allow you to create apps in 14.04 and then deploy them to the emulator running ubuntu touch.
2. Upgrade to 14.10 and future versions of Ubuntu to be able to run on the desktop.

The first method is fully supported by the Ubuntu SDK developers and the easiest way to develop for ubuntu touch. This method is very similar to the android development strategy where developers usually test their app on different versions of android using emulators.

You can find clear instructions on running your app on the emulator [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/sdk/tutorials/using-the-ubuntu-emulator/).